# PGSQL: Adding a variable interval - Syntax error

Tags: postgresql, syntax, syntax-error, plpgsql

I have a quick question. I am fairly new to pgsql and I am unable to figure out how to fix the syntax error below.

Here is what I am trying to do

```
start_date := '2011-01-01'::date;
end_date   := '2011-03-01'::date;
duration := '6 months'

    while start_date < end_date loop
        window_start_date = start_date;
        window_end_date = window_start_date + interval||duration||;

    end loop;
```

However I keep getting a syntax error.

```
ERROR:  column "interval" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT   $1  + interval|| $2 ||
                       ^
QUERY:  SELECT   $1  + interval|| $2 ||
```

What am I doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Your error message doesn't match the code you posted, there is no select statement in your code.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's normal - PL/PgSQL assignments are translated into `SELECT ... INTO` by the parser. The error messages unfortunately don't get converted back.

Comment: @Abhi What did you expect `||` at the end of the statement to do? It doesn't make any sense at all, `||` is the concatenation operator. I think you're trying to write `window_start_date + duration * INTERVAL '1' day` but it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guesswork (the rest of the function definition is missing).
This would work in [**PL/pgSQL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) (which are using behind the curtains):

```
window_end_date := window_start_date + interval duration;
```

Or:

```
window_end_date := window_start_date + duration::interval;
```

- [**Cast**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) the `text` value to `interval` to make it work. But it would be better to declare the variable `duration` as `interval` to begin with (maybe that is the case, then drop the cast - information missing).
- The assignment operator in plpgsql is `:=`, not `=`.
- The result is a `timestamp`, not a `date`. But it will be coerced to `date` in your example.